# Android app loading shared library from incorrect location

Tags: c++11, android-ndk, shared-libraries

I am working on an Android app that is using a c++ shared library. Originally, the project works fine. I recently upgrade the Android Studio to version 4.0.1. I also updated my Gradle version to 4.x but after the update, I have strange problems, so the Gradle version is changed back to 3.6.3.

When the code runs to the statement

```
try{
    System.loadLibrary("something");
} catch(Exception e) {...}
```

The application throws an exception

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZN3Eld12PtrModelRefsEv" referenced by "/data/app/com.myapp-aXvdrU70cJvaDOn1c13zEQ==/lib/arm/libsomething.so"...
```

In the apk file, I can see the library binary file is located in
`apk/debug/app-armeabi-v7a-debug.apk/lib/armeabi-v7a/libsomething.so`

It seems the app is trying to load the shared library from `lib/arm` instead of `lib/armeabi-v7a`

Under the folder `something`, I have the file `build.gradle` configs like:

```
android {
    defaultConfig{
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
        }
    }
}
```

Using the `readelf -A libsomething.so` to check my library file attribute. I have the following result

```
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
  Tag_CPU_name: "ARM v7"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v7
  Tag_CPU_arch_profile: Application
  Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-2
  Tag_FP_arch: VFPv3
  Tag_Advanced_SIMD_arch: NEONv1
  Tag_ABI_PCS_GOT_use: GOT-indirect
  Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
  Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
  Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
  Tag_ABI_enum_size: int
  Tag_CPU_unaligned_access: v6
  Tag_ABI_FP_16bit_format: IEEE 754
```

I tried to use `System.setProperty("java.library.path", "lib/armeabi-v7a");` to change the library loading path. But it does not change anything.

So, how can I let the function `System.loadLibrary` loading the binary library file from the correct location?

Android Studio version: 4.0.1
Android Gradle Plugin Version: 3.6.3
Gradle Version:6.3

Answer (score 0):

I finally found that I forgot to add a CPP file to the make file. `_ZN3Eld12PtrModelRefsEv` is a mangled function name of `PtrModelRefs` which is the most important info I missed. Basically it is saying `undefined function`.